# neither the compiler show any error nor it execute the programm

Tags: c, while-loop

[image]

It just stops after taking inputs for two variables

Comment: look at your second scanf

Comment: A modern compiler *should* show a warning about that....

Answer (score 2):

You need to pass an `int*` to your second `scanf` call.
It should be:

```c
scanf("%d", &f);
```

Comment: Also be handy to check the return value from `scanf`